# Making Web Requests in .NET and waiting for server to return full results

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, performance-testing

I am working on a crude way of performance testing a web application. Basically, I want to execute a web request from .NET to a specific URL that returns some results. The problem I am running in to is that I seem to be getting some type of intermediate page as the results; the results should be a list of objects from a database with a page title of "Advanced Search Results" but my code is delivering content that has a title of "Working...". I was initially trying to do this in PowerShell and seemed to be having the same results so I thought I might have better luck in C#. Here is what I have so far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.IO;

    namespace QTesting
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("https://u.spart.com/u.Int/AdvSearchResults/Person/220001305");
                wr.Method = "GET";
                wr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ultimately, if i can get this working, I want to gather the time it takes to return these results.

Thanks!

Tony

Comment: OK,  so it appears from capturing the traffic in Fiddler that there is a 200 result that is the "Waiting..." page, followed by a 302, followed by another 200 that has all the data I am looking for. Doesn't this mean that it is redirecting?

Comment: Further analysis shows that it IS redirecting because if I turn off the redirection from Safari Jones recommendation, the results are from the 302 page... It must be some kind of Ajax or JS running that populates the page... What property would I be looking for from the original page to send the follow up request? Wouldn't that be the ResponseUri? I've tried initiating another WebRequest after getting the ResponseUri and I get the same results... Is there a certain way I need to make the request?

Comment: Ah, I think I have identified the issue. There is a hidden form that is being submitted. I will have to dig deeper into this... Does anyone know of any good examples of POSTing to a web server or of the full back and forth process?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the page uses AJAX and you first get an empty page with the "Working..." title that is replaced by the JS code when the results are loaded.
You must use a proxy like Fiddler to identify the request that the JS code is sending to the target website and then add it to your testing code: I mean that your code must request the original page and then the new URL. Easily the new URL will answer with a JSON object. 
In this way you will simulate the full page loading server side.
Another approach could be using Selenium that simulate a real browser and you wouldn't need to care about what JS does. It's feasible for functional tests but not for massive load test because the number of Selenium drivers that you can spawn on your machine is limited

Comment: I'll have to give this a try. Do you have any resources on selenium to accomplish this? I've never used that before... Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I usually follow the first approach

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling redirects:

```
 WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("https://u.spart.com/u.Int/AdvSearchResults/Person/220001305");
 wr.MaximumAutomaticRedirections=10;
 wr.AllowAutoRedirect=true;
```

A lot of sites redirect without you realising, by default the WebRequest won't. But you can enable it per above. The maximum is just a placeholder, you can increase or decrease this as your needs arise, but I suggest you leave it in place to avoid infinite redirects or a redirect loop.

Comment: I tried that but Visual Studio is saying that WebRequest does not contain MaximumAutomaticRedirections or AllowAutoRedirection... Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I wrapped the WebRequest in HttpWebRequest and all the errors cleared up, but still no go... The title is still "Working..."